# $RecursionLimit error message when expanding functions around a logarithmic divergence

Tags: warning-messages, series-expansion

Consider the function $f(x) = \sin x \log x$. Although this function is not analytical at $x=0$, I can ask Mathematica to expand it around this point with the function `Series`. When doing so, I get a large amount of `$RecursionLimit` error messages, and finally a correct result:

```
In[43]:= Series[Sin[x] Log[x], {x, 0, 3}]
During evaluation of In[43]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded during evaluation of {{Log[x]},{1}}.
During evaluation of In[43]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded during evaluation of FreeQ[{},x].
During evaluation of In[43]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded during evaluation of NumericQ[x].
During evaluation of In[43]:= General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation.
During evaluation of In[43]:= $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
During evaluation of In[43]:= $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
During evaluation of In[43]:= $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
During evaluation of In[43]:= General::stop: Further output of $IterationLimit::itlim will be suppressed during this calculation.

(* (Log[x] + O[x]^3)(x - x^3/6 + O[x]^4) *)
```

The problem is that I have more complicated expressions and Mathematica takes a considerably large amount of time in performing such computations.

Is there an explanation for this and a way to get rid of them?

Comment: This does look like a bug, but please edit your question to include what version you're using.

Comment: I get no errors, and different result `SeriesData[x, 0, {
Log[x], 0, Rational[-1, 6] Log[x]}, 1, 4, 1]`. On win 10, 64 bit, version 11.2

Comment: no problem in win 10, 64 bit, version 11.1.1. Have you checked if the problem occurs on a fresh kernel?

Comment: I get same result as @Coolwater with v11.2 on a Mac.

Comment: Ok. So I found that this happens only when I have loaded the package [EDCRGTC.m](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/), so it may provoke some conflict in some way.